# Nvme(Kingston A2000) stopts giving response

Tags: ubuntu, ssd, pci, nvme

I installed new nvme in my Inspiron 15 5580. The laptop boots fine with my nvme but the problem is that sometimes it stops responding (not able to read anything).

My laptop was pre installed with windows 10 but currently it is ubuntu 18.04. There might be a possibility of something incompatible.

This generally happens while doing heavy reading/writing.

It sometimes happens at the time of power off and everything hangs so i tried pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>PrtScr</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>,<kbd>E</kbd>,<kbd>I</kbd>,<kbd>S</kbd>,<kbd>U</kbd>,<kbd>B</kbd>. This restart the system without power down. So after restart the bootloader is not able to find my .efi file and shows this:

You can see the output in link below:

[image: IMG:]

Finally, the **nvme doesn't get recognise until i completely power down my laptop and power up again.**

I also checked the temperature of my drive it seems to be fine around **30-45 degree**.

I think there might be some issue with power supply to nvme.

Comment: Sounds like a faulty drive to me. If you just bought it and it's under warranty, you should contact the manufacturer for assistance and/or a replacement.

Comment: I bought it 2 months ago at the I'm facing this issue from the time of installation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of research this worked. The problem was because of **Autonomous Power State Transition**.
So after adding `nvme_core.default_ps_max_latency_us=5500`
it works great.
To do this add this in boot parameter in  `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT in /etc/default/grub file`